# Is there any version control tool workable for NetSuite?

Tags: version-control, netsuite, suitescript2.0

So far, we update the script files by navigating to "Documents > Files > SuiteScripts" in NetSuite.

There seems no version control mechanism in it.

We use Git to control version on localhost and wonder if Git or something else can be used to control the versions of the files in NetSuite.

Is it possible to use RESTlet or Suitelet to control versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is there, it just sounds like you are not using it yet.  I definitely suggest reading up on, and using the SDF (SuiteCloud Development Framework).  It basically moves all of the development into the IDE, allowing deployment/testing/etc/ from the IDE.

Check out the help article here: [SuiteCloud Development Framework](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=book_4702638251.html)